# Akka Http extractor directive for sealed trait hierarchy

Tags: scala, akka-http

It looks like Akka Http is really close to being able to allow you to define an extractor for an ADT, based on what's [already built in](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.10/scala/http/routing-dsl/case-class-extraction.html#case-class-validation) for `case class`. I've tried composing an extractor for a `sealed trait` hierarchy, but it doesn't seem to work, due to the invariance of `Directive`:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._

sealed trait QueryStringOption
case object NoOption extends QueryStringOption
case class OptionA(value: Int) extends QueryStringOption
case class OptionB(value: String) extends QueryStringOption

val noOptionExtractor = provide(NoOption)
val optionAExtractor = parameter('optionA.as[Int]).as(OptionA)
val optionBExtractor = parameter('optionB.as[String]).as(OptionB)

val queryStringOptionExtractor = optionAExtractor | optionBExtractor | noOptionExtractor

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<console>:51: error: type mismatch;
 found   : akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive1[OptionB]
    (which expands to)  akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive[(OptionB,)]
 required: akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive[(Product with Serializable with QueryStringOption,)]
Note: (OptionB,) <: (Product with Serializable with QueryStringOption,), but class Directive is invariant in type L.
You may wish to define L as +L instead. (SLS 4.5)
       val queryStringOptionExtractor = optionAExtractor | optionBExtractor | noOptionExtractor
                                                           ^
```

Is there a better solution here?

Is there a way perhaps to lift my extractors to `Option[_]`? That way, I could combine with `&` at least, and I'd just have to pattern match.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add types, so that the directives have the right type:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive1
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._

sealed trait QueryStringOption
case object NoOption extends QueryStringOption
case class OptionA(value: Int) extends QueryStringOption
case class OptionB(value: String) extends QueryStringOption

val noOptionExtractor: Directive1[QueryStringOption] = provide(NoOption)
val optionAExtractor: Directive1[QueryStringOption] = parameter('optionA.as[Int]).as(OptionA)
val optionBExtractor: Directive1[QueryStringOption] = parameter('optionB.as[String]).as(OptionB)

// should now compile as all alternatives now have the same type
val queryStringOptionExtractor = optionAExtractor | optionBExtractor | noOptionExtractor
```

(Also the example is missing the `extends QueryStringOption` parts, I'll edit to add them)

Comment: I adapted the example from some real code I have, in which I had properly extended the `sealed trait` (thanks for the fix!). But I think that last line, to combine the options into a single extractor, will still fail.

Comment: It compiled for me

Comment: With `val queryStringOptionExtractor = optionAExtractor | optionBExtractor | noOptionExtractor`? Sorry if I'm misunderstanding, but that line isn't currently in your answer.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry. I included only the changed lines. (Will edit)

Comment: In my REPL, this isn't working. I'm still getting a variance error. I'll update my question to show the error.

Comment: I think we are stuck in copy-pasta land :), so you might have lost the type annotations on the way (`: Directive1[QueryStringOption]`) :) I now updated the solution with a complete block which works if I paste it verbatim into a scala console. Hope that fixes it.